# Why is my Ubuntu terminal becoming fully transparent?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and I am facing a problem with the terminal.

Without any particular reason, it suddenly becomes completely transparent (like the inside part of the window or, at times, the command line alone is disappearing) and I don't see what I am writing. I have set it to a 'solid color', and I even tried to play with the transparency percentage but the problem persists.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal. Please make note that terminal wnindows should  be active. 
Go to Unity Panel , choose edit > Preferences > Backgrounds.

Move selector from `none` to `Maximum`.